# Free jqGrid autocomplete disables for inline editing after select

Tags: jquery, autocomplete, free-jqgrid

Here is my grid column code:

```
{name:'Track_Name',index:'isrc.Track_Name', width:195, align:"left", editable:true,
    editoptions:{
        dataInit:function (elem, options) {
            $(elem).autocomplete({
                source: "xtras/search_isrc.php",
                dataType: "json",
                minLength: 2,
                select: function(event, ui) {

                    $grid.jqGrid("setCell", options.rowId, "ISRC", ui.item.ISRC);
                    $grid.jqGrid("setCell", options.rowId, "Track_Name", ui.item.Track_Name);
                    $grid.jqGrid("setCell", options.rowId, "Time", ui.item.Track_Time);
                    $grid.jqGrid("setCell", options.rowId, "ArtistName", ui.item.ArtistName);
                    $grid.jqGrid("setCell", options.rowId, "Writer", ui.item.Writer);
                    $grid.jqGrid("setCell", options.rowId, "Publisher", ui.item.Publisher);
                    $grid.jqGrid("setCell", options.rowId, "Year", ui.item.TrackPLineYear);
                    $grid.jqGrid("setCell", options.rowId, "PInfo", ui.item.TrackPLineInfo);
                    $grid.jqGrid("setCell", options.rowId, "isrc_ID", ui.item.isrc_ID);

                    $("#"+options.rowId+"_Disc").focus();
                },
                change: function(event, ui) {
                    if (ui.item) {
                        $grid.jqGrid("setCell", options.rowId, "ISRC", ui.item.ISRC);
                        $grid.jqGrid("setCell", options.rowId, "Track_Name", ui.item.Track_Name);
                        $grid.jqGrid("setCell", options.rowId, "Time", ui.item.Track_Time);
                        $grid.jqGrid("setCell", options.rowId, "ArtistName", ui.item.ArtistName);
                        $grid.jqGrid("setCell", options.rowId, "Writer", ui.item.Writer);
                        $grid.jqGrid("setCell", options.rowId, "Publisher", ui.item.Publisher);
                        $grid.jqGrid("setCell", options.rowId, "Year", ui.item.TrackPLineYear);
                        $grid.jqGrid("setCell", options.rowId, "PInfo", ui.item.TrackPLineInfo);
                        $grid.jqGrid("setCell", options.rowId, "isrc_ID", ui.item.isrc_ID);
                        $("#"+options.rowId+"_Disc").focus();
                    }
                }
            });
            $('.ui-autocomplete').css('zIndex',1000); 

            if (options.mode !== "add") {
                $(elem).css({'border':'1px solid red','background-color':'#e8b7cf'});
            }
        }
    }
},
```

All above mentioned cells are visible and editable apart from `isrc_ID`, which is editable, but hidden.
Here is what `search_isrc.php` returns:

```
$row_array['label']             = $data['Track_Name'];
$row_array['ISRC']              = $data['ISRC'];   
$row_array['Track_Name']        = $data['Track_Name'];
$row_array['ArtistName']        = $data['ArtistName']; 
$row_array['Track_Time']        = $data['Track_Time'];
$row_array['Writer']            = $data['Writer']; 
$row_array['Publisher']         = $data['Publisher']; 
$row_array['TrackPLineYear']    = $data['TrackPLineYear']; 
$row_array['TrackPLineInfo']    = $data['TrackPLineInfo']; 
$row_array['isrc_ID']           = $data['isrc_ID'];
```

Here is inline editing trigger:

```
ondblClickRow: function (rowid) {
    var savedRows = $grid.jqGrid("getGridParam", "savedRow");
    $grid.jqGrid("setSelection", rowid);

    if (savedRows.length > 0 && savedRows[0].id !== rowid) {
        // cancel editing of another row is editing
        // don't cancel on double click on the current editing
        $grid.jqGrid("restoreRow", savedRows[0].id);
    }
    if (savedRows.length === 0) {
        $grid.jqGrid("editRow", rowid, editOptions);
    } 
}
```

This selects, displays and sends correct values as expected. My problem is that after selecting a value all above cells becomes disabled for editing. How can I prevent this behaviour?

--------------------UPDATE---------------------

jqGrid 4.13.0 - free jqGrid

jquery-1.11.0.min.js

listed columns in `select` and `change` events are all `editable:true`
- the goal is to fill in the data into those cells

`$("#"+options.rowId+"_Disc").focus();` - is there just to put focus into specific cell after an autocomplete data was selected.

Comment: Which versions of free jqGrid and jQuery UI you use? For example I don't know about `dataType: "json"` option of `autocomplete`. Which columns are editable in the grid? You use `setCell` for many columns inside of `select` and `change` event. What is the goal of that? Is all the columns non-editable? The statement "editable apart from isrc_ID" is not clear enough because you didn't included `colModel`.  What goal of the line `$("#"+options.rowId+"_Disc").focus();`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to me that the origin of your problem is the usage of `setCell` on cells which are **in editing mode**. One can't do this. The `setCell` will just set new HTML content on the cells (innerHTML of `<td>` elements) and the `<input>`, `<select>` and other editing controls will be removed from the row. If you really need to use set the values in the corresponding controls then you should access in input elements by ids.

The id of controls of inline editing row will be build based on `rowid` as the prefix, the underscore character `_` and the name of the column. For example the code fragment

```
$grid.jqGrid("setCell", options.rowId, "ISRC", ui.item.ISRC);
$grid.jqGrid("setCell", options.rowId, "Track_Name", ui.item.Track_Name);
$grid.jqGrid("setCell", options.rowId, "Time", ui.item.Track_Time);
...
```

should be rewritten like

```
var idPrefix = "#" + options.rowId + "_", item = ui.item;
$(idPrefix + "ISRC").val(item.ISRC);
$(idPrefix + "Track_Name").val(item.Track_Name);
$(idPrefix + "Time").val(item.Track_Time);
...
```

Moreover you should remove non-existing option `dataType: "json"` of jQuery UI Autocomplete and unneeded property `align:"left"` of `colModel`.

Comment: @Elen: I suggested to use non for editable column, but for `editable: "hidden"`. Such fields are not editable, but the values of the columns will be sent to the server.

Comment: @Elen: It's no problem. The most important is to solve the existing problem.